# Rally pyral sdk error with a query with more than two terms. (Error parsing expression -- expected ")" but saw "AND" instead.)

Tags: python, rally

I am using pyral, [the Rally python SDK](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/python-toolkit-rally-rest-api), I format my query string with a tuple, but it appears that any time I have more than two terms it fails. Here is my test code:

```
import pyral

rally = pyral.Rally('rally1.rallydev.com', 'user@example.com', 'password')

user = rally.getUserInfo(name='User Name').pop(0)
wksp = rally.getWorkspace()
proj = rally.getProject()

print user.FirstName, user.LastName
print wksp.Name
print proj.Name

queryStrings = (
('State != "Closed"', 'Owner = ' + user.ref),
('State != "Fixed"', 'Owner = ' + user.ref),
('State != "Closed"', 'State != "Fixed"'),
('State != "Closed"', 'State != "Fixed"', 'Owner = ' + user.ref),
('State != Closed', 'State != Fixed', 'State != Submitted'),
('State != Fixed', 'ScheduleState != Tested'),
('State != Fixed', 'Owner = ' + user.ref, 'ScheduleState != Tested'),
)

for query in queryStrings:
    print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    print "Query:",query
    defects = rally.get("Defect", True, query=query)
    print "Number of results:",defects.resultCount
    print "Errors:", defects.errors
    print
```

And here is the resulting output

```
User Name
A Workspace
Web Project
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Query: ('State != "Closed"', u'Owner = user/1234567890')
QUERYJUNK: ((State != "Closed") AND (Owner = user/1234567890))
Number of results: 25
Errors: []

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Query: ('State != "Fixed"', u'Owner = user/1234567890')
QUERYJUNK: ((State != "Fixed") AND (Owner = user/1234567890))
Number of results: 89
Errors: []

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Query: ('State != "Closed"', 'State != "Fixed"')
QUERYJUNK: ((State != "Closed") AND (State != "Fixed"))
Number of results: 149
Errors: []

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Query: ('State != "Closed"', 'State != "Fixed"', u'Owner = user/1234567890')
QUERYJUNK: ((State != "Closed") AND (State != "Fixed") AND (Owner = user/1234567890))
Number of results: 0
Errors: [u'Could not parse: Error parsing expression -- expected ")" but saw "AND"       instead.']

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Query: ('State != Closed', 'State != Fixed', 'State != Submitted')
QUERYJUNK: ((State != Closed) AND (State != Fixed) AND (State != Submitted))
Number of results: 0
Errors: [u'Could not parse: Error parsing expression -- expected ")" but saw "AND" instead.']

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Query: ('State != Fixed', 'ScheduleState != Tested')
QUERYJUNK: ((State != Fixed) AND (ScheduleState != Tested))
Number of results: 247
Errors: []

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Query: ('State != Fixed', u'Owner = user/1234567890', 'ScheduleState != Tested')
QUERYJUNK: ((State != Fixed) AND (Owner = user/1234567890) AND (ScheduleState !=     Tested))
Number of results: 0
Errors: [u'Could not parse: Error parsing expression -- expected ")" but saw "AND" instead.']
```

The QUERYJUNK is the output of the query string built by the Rally SDK itself, before it sends it to the rally service.

**EDIT:**

Since this is a bug in the SDK itself per Kyle's answer, I created a work around in my script until the SDK can be fixed.

```
def buildQueryString(querySequence):
if type(query) in [types.ListType, types.TupleType]:
    seq = ["(%s)" % (s,) for s in querySequence]
    qs = "%s" % seq.pop(0)
    for qt in seq:
        qs = "(%s AND %s)" % (qs, qt)
    print "QS:",qs
    return qs

return querySequence
```

I then pass this string generated into the API, and everything appears to work now. It looks like the API also supports dictionaries for the query parameter, but since it was undocumented, and I don't need it, I did not create a work around for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in pyral generating query strings with more than 2 clauses.

Is currently:

```
((State != Closed) AND (State != Fixed) AND (State != Submitted))
```

Should be:

```
(((State != Closed) AND (State != Fixed)) AND (State != Submitted))
```

We will work to get this fixed soon and open source it on github so the community can better address issues like this.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any technical reason the first form is not allowed? They are logically equivalent.

Comment: The WSAPI query grammar is parsed by a very basic recursive descent algorithm, so basically every clause needs to be of the form (left op right).  Even if all the operations are ANDs or ORs each clause still needs to be of that form.